# How to compress / reduce quality of base64 image with php?

Tags: php, base64

I have stored multiple images in base64 inside my database. I get images  using php as image path. But I want to reduce size of my image when decoding it from base64, because it slows down my app if I load full size image. (Full size image I need just in backend).

```
/* 

DB stuff getting base64 string from database

$img = base64 string (can be with 'data:image/jpg;base64,' in front, thats for the str_replace())
*/

if($img){
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  echo base64_decode(str_replace("data:image/jpg;base64,","",$img));
}
```

Everything works nice this way. I use it like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/getimg.php?id=4" />
```

or in css. I need this because of security reasons, I cant store any image on server, also in path I have `access_token` variable, so random person cant see images.

Is there a way to do this without storing the actual image in server?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here? Do you want to reduce the image quality? Or store the images somewhere else? If its store images somewhere else, WHERE do you want to store them

Comment: If you want to reduce the image quality, that would better be done as part of the image creation, as it will have to be an image and not a base64 string in order for you to do any image convertion on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `imagecreatefromstring` and `imagecopyresized`.

Live example [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sabq-g665)

```
<?php
if ($img) {
    $percent = 0.5;

    // Content type
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);
    $newwidth = $width * $percent;
    $newheight = $height * $percent;

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    // Resize
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($thumb);
}
```